# support for new browsers in organised way

Tags: javascript

We have a old Web Based application supported on browsers from IE6 to IE8 and javascript and css is very specific to the IE. Now we want to support IE9. In our javascript there are many syntaxes that are not supported in IE9, like accessing HTML attributes on element instances using dot (`.`) rather than `setAttribute` and `getAttribute`.

I was just wondering what is best way forward to support more browsers versions or support different browsers.

I was thinking like using jQuery to access non-standard features for all browsers or write a class called browser has method like `getAttribute` and then different class like IE7 and IE9 override this method on load in their specific way.

I want to use best way forward and approach used by users in such a scenrio.

setAttribute and GetAttribute are just simple examples there are many more for example to access the element reference we use document.all.elementName which is not supported in earlier versions of firefox etc. So how to convert all this code to Jquery or another library.
there are more problems then set and get attribute, the focus of question is what is best way to convert old javascript to supported javascript across all the browsers

Thanks

Comment: I would definitely advise going down the jQuery route because I have done exactly the same thing (used it to target different browser/versions) and more often that not, it works a treat.

Comment: What you write about using "setAttribute" and "getAttribute" makes me think you've got more problems than you know, as those were not always the correct things to do on the old browsers either. In fact, a good variety of things absolutely would *not* work if you used those mechanisms to access things that should be treated as DOM element properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a large amount of code written specifically for IE < 9 that you wish to work in other browsers, you first need to identify all the IE specific code and then replace it with cross-browser code. I don't think any particular library will help with that, in fact POJS is likely easier.

For example, you can do a supervised replacement of `document.all` with `document.getElementById`, but you can't do that with $ (where $ is from jQuery or Prototype or whatever).

You'll have issues using dot property access with **non-standard** attributes, but if they are set as properties, you'll be fine (though it's not a good idea to do so in principle).

Incidentally, jQuery doesn't "override" get/setAttribute, it has its own `attr` and `prop` methods.

Ultimately, you'll likely end up rewriting the whole thing from scratch. Just remember, don't target particular browser versions, support standards and address non-standard behaviour where necessary using [feature detection](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/#detectBrowser) and a good fallback strategy.

Comment: thanks for feedback, I like the advice to use feature detection rather than check browser

Answer (score 2):

Definitely recommend going with a library to smooth over browser differences and provide a lot of useful utility functionality. There are lots of choices: [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries). jQuery is [hugely dominant at the moment](http://trends.builtwith.com/javascript) thus making it easier to find people familiar with it (and it has active development resources, sponsorship, etc.), but which library you choose is up to you.

Also strongly recommend looking closely at the [DOM2 HTML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/) and the [Web Application APIs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#webappapis) section of the HTML5 spec, because there are times you want to use the reflected property of an attribute rather than `getAttribute` / `setAttribute`. For instance, `element.id` is a perfectly valid cross-browser way to reference the element's ID; you don't need to use `element.getAttribute("id")`. Similarly, you want to use `element.className` and not `element.getAttribute("class")` (which works incorrectly on some earlier versions of IE). It's true that IE8 and earlier also put other properties on elements for arbitrary attributes (e.g., if you had a `foo` attribute on an element, you could access it as `element.foo`, or if you had `data-foo` you could use `element['data-foo']`) while IE9 and other browsers don't *(for good reason!)*, but for the standard properties there's frequently a reflected property.

If you're using arbitrary attributes on elements, also recommend changing their names to [the `data-*` format](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes) per the HTML5 specification.

Comment: thanks for feedback, if i go with any library, it will be jquery and thanks for useful links.

Answer (score 2):

IE 9 absolutely does support accessing DOM properties that reflect HTML attributes, in common with all major browsers released in the last 15 years, so I'm not sure where you heard that it doesn't *[Edit: Aaaah, I guess you're talking about custom attributes]*. These properties are standardized in DOM specs so are guaranteed to work in future browsers. Furthermore, it is usually more convenient and more compatible to use properties rather than `getAttribute()` and `setAttribute()` (particularly in older IE, which has broken implementations of these methods).

Libraries such as jQuery do help smooth over browser problems and incompatibilities but in truth these are not nearly as numerous or problematic as many people believe, especially when you can discount older versions of IE. The very existence of these libraries has created the popular myth that DOM manipulation in browsers is difficult and problematic without them. Generally, it isn't, and these days the problems are better understood and documented than ever.

Comment: thanks for feedback, I do agree that libraries add extra layer and stop developer from understanding underlying language.

Comment: @daljit: If a developer allows using a library to prevent their understanding how JS and the DOM work, that's down to the developer, not the library. I for one have no interest in debugging rare oddities in, say, Safari that other people have already found and worked around. And I'd *much* rather use the utility functionality provided by a good library than recreate it (recreate because virtually no one's going to want to type out all of that verbose stuff over and over and over). My two cents. Absolutely ensure you know what's really going on, but don't throw out the baby with the bathwater.

Comment: Thanks Crowder for the feedback. I like the catchphrase. It is true, so am still undecided. I like Jquery and may be use that if i do with external library.